# How to make QR Code in crystal reports Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I need to include QR code in Crystal reports 
SO i need to embed information like address or e-mail 
Can any one explaining how to do this using .NET environment ( visual studio )

Comment: You can use this one it is free -> https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article best answers your question
http://kenhamady.com/cru/archives/2342
The article suggests, If you need to generate QR codes on the fly from your report data, one option is to use a dll that can encode the data and a special font to convert that data into the QR Code.there are two vendors that sell a combination like this that.  They are the "QR Code Font and Encoder by IDAutomation" and "QR Code by Barcodesoft."Both have a free trial.
Another option for stand-alone Crystal Reports is using CUT Light by Millet Software.  This is a UFL  with formula functions, and one of them can generate a QR Code from a formula.  The code is generated as an image so it does not require a special font.